# Align generic elements so they fill up

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to align elements of various sizes so they fill up the space. Let me explain.

Using "display: inline-block" I can achieve this:

[image: display: inline-block]

What I would like is that the third element takes up the empty space, since there's enough room for it e.g.:

[image: Intended result]

Bear in mind that the intention is that it should work generically of various sizes, so I can't place the elements fixed of any kind. I have tried with flex, but it doesn't seem to be able to achieve what I want.

Comment: I think it can be done with JavaScript, but not with pure CSS. I was looking for something like that (pure CSS) for a project but I couldn't find anything (yet) :(

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Did you solve it using a js library or did you solve it yourself?

Comment: I used a jquery gallery plugin for that. I don't remember the name of it (sorry) but it did the job. I'm still looking for a solution to do it without JS if that is possible.

Comment: My use case is for arranging widgets in an Angular application. I'm still in a very early stage where I try to figure out what is possible. If what I'm trying to do here isn't possible, I think I'll use css grid.

Comment: Yes grid always helps. You can use jQuery though if that layout is necessary.